# Add an html to an element under PHP condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an HTML next to an existing element in my page. This is what I've tried::

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?php 
if ( $duedatereservation < $today ) {
//echo "Past Due!";
$isPastDue = true;
}    
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Transaction Date</div>
  <div class="inner">Due Date</div>
</div>
<h2 id="report">Notice</h2>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<span>Past Due!</span>").insertAfter("#report");
});
```

What exactly I want is when the condition $isPastDue is true, I want to append/add a  html tag next to #report h2. But it's not displaying. Any ideas? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
<?php 
if ( $duedatereservation < $today ) {
//echo "Past Due!";
$isPastDue = true;
}    
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Transaction Date</div>
  <div class="inner">Due Date</div>
</div>
<h2 id="report">Notice</h2>
<?php if($isPastDue):?>
  <span>Past Due!</span>
<?php endif;?>
```

If your requirement this much, no need to add JavaScript.Just use only php.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
<?php
if($isPastDue) {
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("<span>Past Due!</span>").insertAfter("#report");
    });
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the main case is you want to execute the `insertAfter` script only if `isPastDue` is `true`. You can do it by echo the `insertAfter` script before closing `}` of your PHP `if` condition.

```
<?php
if($duedatereservation < $today){
    echo '<script>';
    echo '...
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use JQuery for this. You can do this using PHP only

```
<h2 id="report">Notice <?php if($isPastDue){echo "<span>Past Due!</span>";} </h2>
```